# In JQL I have a result set of issues. I would like to query for the set of Epics that contain these issues. these epics can be in multiple projects

Tags: jira, jql

I have a release in a single Jira project, that is described by multiple epics in multiple Jira projects.
Given that I can query the issues in my project and return a set of issues in my release, I would also like a query that would just return the epics, across multiple Jira projects, related to those issues in my release.

I don't know where to begin, I have searched for answers but everything I find is based on finding issues contained by a set of epics, and not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
issueFunction in epicsOf("<original query goes here>").
```

Sorry for posting such an easy question.